# Can different tables have columns with the same name if those columns are not primary keys?

Tags: database-design, primary-key

I know it's a simple enough question but my textbook is very confusing about it.

Comment: Please edit what you "really wanted to know" into your question.

Answer (score 9):

SQL employs a concept known as **domain name integrity** which means that the names of objects have a scope given by their container.

Column names have to be unique, but only within the context of the table that contains the columns. Table names have to be unique, but only within the context of the schema that contains the tables, etc.

When you query columns you need to reference the schema, table and column that you are interested in, unless one or more of these can be inferred. When you write a query, you need to reference the tables in your query by name directly or by using an alias, e.g. Customer.ID or C.ID from Customer C, etc., unless your query is so simple that it only references one table.

There was a time when there was a technical requirement for uniqueness of all column names, which applied to old ISAM databases and to languages like COBOL in the 1960s and 70s. This got dragged along for no good reason into dBase in the 1980s and has stuck as a convention well into the relational and object DBMS eras. Resist this outdated convention.

When the shift from flat file and network databases to relational databases happened in the 1970s and 80s, the idea of joining tables was new.  So some people chose the convention that a unique name could be repeated if one column was a reference to another (i.e. foreign keys).  This concept is called a "natural join" and a lot of people still advocate for doing this.

I am not a fan of natural joins because it requires you, ultimately, to throw out the concept of domain name integrity and force the whole column reference into the column name.

The issue with natural joins is that you either have to be hypocritical or you have to make your column names long and unreadable.  Let me illustrate: It may sound like a good idea that the primary key of the Customer table is CustomerID.  Then in your Invoice table, your foreign key to Customer is also called CustomerID.  This would be a natural join and it all sounds good so far.  Here is the problem.  What if your convention is to have a column on every table called LastUpdatedDate?  So are you meant to join every table to every other table by LastUpdatedDate?  Of course not.  This is the absurdity of natural joins.  In order to avoid this absurdity you would need to jam the table name into the column name as a prefix.  However, if you have multiple schemas in your database, you can't stop there.  You also need to add the schema to the column name, and so it goes.

Another place where natural joins break down is when you have multiple relationships between the same two tables.  You if you need two references to Employee on your Invoice table (Sold By and Approved By, for example) you can't call them both EmployeeID.

Comment: Good answer, regarding natural join I dislike it too. I would like to see a new kind of join, let's call it ref join in lack of a better word. The join predicate would be derived from the foreign key relationship between the parent and the child table. In the choice of a Cartesian product and an empty set as a result of a ref join between unrelated tables I think the latter is better. Perhaps even better would be an exception in those cases.

Answer (score 3):

A simple analogy.

Think of two different people in the same postal district (database schema) having the same address (table name) and name (field name). What's the poor postman going to do?

You'll have to check the system catalogue (you didn't specify your RDBMS) - but I'd be very surprised if any of the major RDBMSs allowed it! Normally, there's a `UNIQUE` constraint on fieldnames within the same table.

What with using keywords as fieldnames and using quoted identifiers (for lower-case/upper-case mixing), some RDBMSs do both, the potential for buggy code would go through the ceiling if this idea were allowed. You would have to impose a constraint on SQL queries about the ordering of fields in the query to unambiguously identify the returned values - a "[coding horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/) *".

What if you specify MyTable with fields `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f1` and then do a `SELECT f2, f1 FROM MyTable`? Which `f1` is it?

A database (management system) shouldn't care what the order of the fieldnames is. What's **even worse** is that this is a clear breach of [Codd's Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules)

> - Rule 2: The guaranteed access rule:
>
> Each and every datum (atomic value) in a relational data base is
>   guaranteed to be logically accessible by resorting to a combination of
>   table name, primary key value and column name."
>
> ["column name" in this case is also the field name]

Maybe that's what you're looking for in a "textbook" sense - Codd's Rules can be found in most introductory books on RDBMSs.

BTW, welcome to the site :-) Here, we encourage people to do a bit of work for themselves - you could, as @Marco suggested, have tried it for yourself. Take the site tour, check out the "Help us to help you" blog (both bottom left of page) and also the Help Centre (top right).

These sites are a great resource and you will get all the more out of them by following the guidelines.

(*) great site for exposing more of these.